# Intellij IDEA - for git commit message to start with some keyword

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Can I force a git commit message to start with some text

something like:

```
feature: add something to UI
```

or

```
bug: fix login page error
```

The commit message must start with "feature:" in the above case or with "bug:" as the second example shows

if the message does not start with "feature:" or "bug:" I would like to reject the commit

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it

1. Go to your home directory and create a folder named hooks. And create hook files.

   ```
   mkdir ~/hooks
   cd ~/hooks

   touch pre-commit
   chmod +x pre-commit

   touch commit-msg
   chmod +x commit-msg
   ```
2. Our first argument $1 gives us the commit-msg file. We can read the commit message with the following command:

   ```
   cat "$1"
   ```
3. Create this script file (Here REGEX_ISSUE_ID contains the REGEX that you want to set for your commit message format)

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   REGEX_ISSUE_ID="^(ISSUE-[0-9]+|Merge|hotfix)"
   ISSUE_ID_IN_COMMIT=$(echo $(cat "$1") | grep -o -E "$REGEX_ISSUE_ID")

   if [[ -z "$ISSUE_ID_IN_COMMIT" ]]; then
       BRANCH_NAME=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
       ISSUE_ID=$(echo "$BRANCH_NAME" | grep -o -E "$REGEX_ISSUE_ID")

       if [[ -z "$ISSUE_ID" ]]; then
           echo "[commit-msg-hook] Your commit message is illegal. Please rename        your branch with using following regex: $REGEX_ISSUE_ID"
           exit 1
       fi

       echo "$ISSUE_ID | $(cat "$1")" > "$1"
   fi
   ```
4. Go to the project folder and run the following command to use your hooks. You need to make this for every project that you want to use hooks.

   ```
   cd <your-team-repository>
   git config core.hooksPath ~/hooks
   ```

You can find more information here: https://ahmetcan.org/git-hooks-enforce-commit-message-and-branch-name/